# Python: how to code a "response" based on user input when given multiple options?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and writing a simple program that is basically just an interactive conversation. I am asking the following question:

What is your name?
What is your gender?
What is your favorite color?
What is your birth year?
Do you have any pets?
etc.

The idea is to create as many response variables for each question as I can. For example: for "what is your gender?" if the user enters male, I want the response to be "Nice to meet you dude!", and if the user enters female I want the response to be "Nice to meet you miss!"

I would also like for the question "What is your birth year" to be met with a response that says You're "age"? You are so old!" (or something similar).

Below is what I have so far:

```
name = input('What is your name? ')
print('Hi ' + name + '!')
gender = input('What is your gender? ')
is_male = True
if is_male:
    print('Nice to meet you, dude!')
else:
    print('Nice to meet you, miss!')
favorite_color = input('What is your favorite color? ')
print(favorite_color + '? I love ' + favorite_color)
birth_year = input('What is your birth year? ')
age = 2021 - int(birth_year)
print(age + '? You are so old! ')
pets = input('Do you have any pets? ')
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What exactly is your question here? There are a few optimization and safety checking things in your code but most of it works as is. By most, I mean your gender check doesn't work but the rest should work as is. There are a few better ways to format the responses but that's not huge.

Comment: You may be interested in https://www.upgrad.com/blog/how-to-make-chatbot-in-python/ or https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20990/40769

Comment: Here's an article on Structural Pattern Matching, a very nice feature introduced in Python 3.10 that may be exactly what you need: https://benhoyt.com/writings/python-pattern-matching/

Comment: Thank you all so much! This is totally new to me, so I appreciate all the feedback and links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found two bugs. Here, `is_male` is always True, so you'll always get the "dude" statement. And in case of age, age is int, so you can't concatenate int and str. Instead you can use fstring. Your corrected code:

```
name = input('What is your name? ')
print('Hi ' + name + '!')
gender = input('What is your gender? ')
if gender.lower()=="male" or gender.lower()=="m":
    print('Nice to meet you, dude!')
else:
    print('Nice to meet you, miss!')
favorite_color = input('What is your favorite color? ')
print(favorite_color + '? I love ' + favorite_color)
birth_year = input('What is your birth year? ')
age = 2021 - int(birth_year)
print(f'{age}? You are so old! ')
pets = input('Do you have any pets? ')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank yo so much!

Comment: Can accept my answer if worked

Comment: Sorry - new here, didn't know I needed to do that. Got it taken care of!

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 2):

So you did most of it but you took an input

> gender

but you did not use it
here:

```
is_male = True
if is_male:
```

this is_male is always true, you should read the input there instead of hardcoding it and give the user choices here like [M/F]
then you can continue like this
if gender == "M":

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert an integer to string using `str()` when you concatenate a string with an integer.

```
age = 2021 - int(birth_year)
print('Your ' +str(age) + '? You are so old! ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the *elif* statement like the following:

```
is_male = False
is_female = False
birth_year = input('What is your birth year? ')
age = 2021 - int(birth_year)

if age < 16:
    print("Hello youngster.")
elif 16 <= age < 30:
    print(r"Don't trust anyone over 30!")
elif 30 <= age < 50:
    print("Metallica rules!")
else:
    print("Take a nap.  You deserve it.")

male_list = ["Bob", "Don","Joshua", "Cary", "Sachith" ]
female_list = ["Linda", "Tina","Janice", "Grace", "Stevie Nicks" ]
name = input('What is your name? ')

if name in male_list:
    is_male = True
elif name in female_list:
    is_female = True

if is_male:
    print(f"Dude! Good to see you again {name}.")
elif is_female:
    print(f"Good to see you again {name} my lady.")
else:
    print(f'Nice to meet you {name}, we have not met.')
favorite_color = input('What is your favorite color? ')
print(f"{favorite_color} ? I love {favorite_color}")
```

Comment: Haha, I love all of the responses. This is awesome! In this case, do I need to have all male and female names added to the list in order for it to determine if the user is male or female?

Comment: You should mark one as the answer and vote up the ones that are useful.

Comment: You could change the last else: statement to ask for gender if the name is not in the male or female list.  Then assign is_male or is_female to true or false.